# How to define a namespace based template class or function in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

In C#, could I define a class like this, `T` is a namespace name here, in stead of a data type name.

```
public class MyClass<T> 
{
    T.DataType_Defined_in_T t;
    ...........    
}
```

or in a function:

```
public void MyFunction<T>(T.DataType_Defined_in_T t) 
{
   ...............
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Or, something can switch the reference using in run-time:

between:

```
using namespace  np1;
```

and

```
using namespace  np2;
```

Comment: How `MyClass` not already know the type of itself?  Or are you saying you want to create a type, and that type is located in another class?  I don't see the advantage to this, if you already know what T is then why have another class be a dependency?

Comment: I have two references I can use, they have almost the same data types, sounds weird? but it is true.  I want my class can work for both referenced dlls.

Comment: Makes almost no sense.  But you could create two class Libraries, with the same namespace, and for each project reference the correct library, then your MyClass will use the one the project has a reference for.  This would be SO Much easier if you [included the real code you use, and not some tiny off-question code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using namespaces, but you could implement a class that acts as an accessor or factory for the types in the namespace.

```
interface IFactory
{
    Type GetType1();
}

namespace X
{
    public class Type1 { }

    public class Factory : IFactory
    {
        public Type GetType1() { return typeof(Type1); }
    }
}

namespace Y
{
    public class Type1 { }

    public class Factory : IFactory
    {
        public Type GetType1() { return typeof(Type1); }
    }
}

public void MyFunction<T>(T factory)
    where T : IFactory
{
    var type = factory.GetType1();
    ...
}

void Main()
{
    MyFunction(new X.Factory());
    MyFunction(new Y.Factory());
}
```

Or you would implement a non-generic reflection solution:

```
public void MyFunction(string ns)
{
    var typesReader = from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                      from type in asm.GetExportedTypes()
                      where type.Namespace == ns
                      select type;

    var typeMap = typesReader.ToDictionary(t => t.Name);

    var type1 = typeMap["Type1"];

    ...
}

void Main()
{
    MyFunction("X");
    MyFunction("Y");
}
```

Note that this reflection solution won't work if the assembly(-ies) containing the namespace(s) aren't loaded in the appdomain yet.

Comment: Thanks,Michael. But in my case, I already wrote a class, lots of functions in there, lots of data types are from a referenced dll I am using, but suddenly came out another module i need to use, it has almost the same data types. I don't want to rewrite those code,I want to share the same code i wrote.

Comment: Sounds more like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858) now.  Instead of asking if this solution exists, state what you currently have (with code) and ask how it can be used across different assemblies.

Comment: @Gisway: Your options are limited. Either you'll end up with a OO solution like I proposed above, or you'll end up with a reflection solution. Would you prefer reflection?

Comment: I prefer the reflection one.

Comment: Given your initial question, it would seem type safety is a concern, but if you're OK with reflection (not type safe at compile time), I'll update my answer.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may also want to consider an AOP solution, such as you might be able to get with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

Comment: I haven't tried the reflection solution yet, will it pass the compilation for the run-time data types. I mean if I just follow your     '...': type1 v1 = new type1(); v1.blabla = blabla.

Comment: I'll leave that for you to implement. See [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wccyzw83). Note that without a common interface on types, you'll either have to use [dynamics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) or use a reflection solution where you manually look up and/or invoke the methods/properties/etc. Reflection is ugly and slow. Dynamics are prettier but very slow. An OO solution using interfaces is fast and typesafe but invasive.